# High Charts Center Series Label

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm working with High Charts (http://www.highcharts.com/) to get some interactive charts for my webpage. I'm attempting to create a timeline of sorts using a column range chart and a bunch of series.

http://jsfiddle.net/asrm5zL0/

```
dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'middle',
                crop: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                formatter: function () { return 'CenterThis' }
            }
```

Currently I've created the above example. I've been trying to find a way to center the labels for a given series in the bar itself, however it seems to always want to label each data point. Is there a simple way to do this that I'm not seeing? The high charts documentation for series (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels) didn't seem to have a property for this sort of thing.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a single data label for each bar? If so, what do you want the value to be?  There is not a simple solution for this, as far as I know. I would approach this with a separate scatter series, using the center of the range as the y value, and apply the data labels to that series.

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to get a single data label for each bar. The value would be determined by a simple function. Do you have an example of a scatter series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `inside` to true for `dataLabels`.

```
             ...
             dataLabels: {
                 align: 'center',
                 inside: true,
             ...
```

[API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<arearange>.dataLabels.inside), example: http://jsfiddle.net/asrm5zL0/7/

Comment: The problem with that is when you add it to a larger series, it still shows twice, once at each data point in the series.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/asrm5zL0/5/

Comment: @NightTrain My mistake - add align: 'center' and labels are centered. (Align can be left, right or center - not middle) Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Example using a scatter series to split the difference:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/asrm5zL0/9/

.

```
{
    linkedTo: ':prev',
    name: 'Data Label Series',
    type: 'scatter',
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    marker: { radius : 0 },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        style: {
            fontSize:'.75em',
            fontWeight: 'normal'
        },
        formatter: function () { return 'CenterThis' }
    },
    data: [[3, Date.UTC(2015, 09, 01, 17, 30, 0)]]
}
```